# Have GCC give warnings for the preprocessed file

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, gcc-warning

GCC shows line numbers for the .c file, which in my case is a macro that is defined using other macros, which are defined using even more macros, etc. Is there a way to have GCC give the line numbers for the preprocessed .i file instead?

bla.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(a) printf("%d\n", (a));

int main()
{
    double a = 2.5;

    PRINT(a);

    return 0;
}
```

It will print the warning for the line containing PRINT(a) (line 10), but I want it to print the line containing printf("%d\n", (a));; from the preprocessed file (line 1837)

preprocessed file:

```
<other code above>
int main()
{
 double a = 2.5;

 printf("%d\n", (a));;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. So you want line number _or_ a warning? Which line number do you want? What warnings are you interested in? For code analysis, use an tools for that, like an  IDE - for example Eclipse comes with a custom implementation of preprocessor for browsing source code.

Comment: @KamilCuk I want the warning to give the line number of the preprocessed program, and not the C program. I will edit my question with an example.

Comment: If you want gcc to give the line numbers of errors in code generated from macro expansion, then this is likely not possible, because macros are per definition defined on a  single logical source line.
I'd recommend preprocessing your files once with `gcc -E`, then run a code formatter, e.g. `clang-format`, and finally compile the resulting code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the options `-no-integrated-cpp -P` to get:

```
/tmp/ccQ2ECah.i: In function 'main':
/tmp/ccQ2ECah.i:729:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
  729 |     printf("%d\n", (a));;
      |             ~^     ~~~
      |              |     |
      |              int   double
      |             %f
```

The `-no-integrated-cpp` option causes the preprocessor and compiler to run as truly separate passes, where the only communication between them is the preprocessor output.

In this mode, the preprocessor would normally include [`#line` directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) in its output to identify source line numbers from the original file.  The `-P` option suppresses them.  Then the compiler pass has no information about the original file's line numbers, and can only print the line numbers of the preprocessor output.